# Tensorflow customerize training - ValueError: Variable dense/kernel/Adam/ does not exist?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to build a very simple NN model to do classification task. I try to build the model with customerize way. And I want to use `tf.Data.Dataset` to load my dataset. Then I train the model with `mini-batch` way. Meantime, I want to print the model result on validate dataset. So I try to reuse variables. My model is as follows:

```
def get_loss(prediction, label):
    return tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(tf.expand_dims(label, -1), prediction)


def make_train_op(optimizer, loss):
    apply_gradient_op = optimizer.minimize(loss,)
    return apply_gradient_op

class Model:

    def __init__(self):
        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, input_shape=(3,), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(64,), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(128,), activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)
    ])

    def __call__(self, inp, is_train=True):
        return self.model(inp.feature), inp.label
```

Then I try to train this model as follows:

```
model = Model()
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()

with tf.variable_scope('input', reuse=True):
    training_inp = InputPipe()
    validate_inp = InputPipe(is_train=False)

scope = tf.get_variable_scope()
training_prediction, true_train_y = model(training_inp)
scope.reuse_variables()

total_instances = data_size * n_repeats
steps_per_epoch = data_size // batch_size if data_size / batch_size == 0 else data_size // batch_size + 1

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    training_inp.init_sess(sess)
    list_grads = []
    for epoch in range(n_repeats):
        tqr = range(steps_per_epoch)

        for _ in tqr:
            loss = get_loss(training_prediction, true_train_y)
            sess.run(make_train_op(optimizer, loss))
```

However, the `optimizer.minize(loss)` throws an exception:

> ValueError: Variable dense/kernel/Adam/ does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?

**UPDATE:**

When I call `get_loss` and `make_train_op` out of the loop. It raises another error about `FailedPreconditionError` However, I have already initlized all variables:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback):
>
> Error while reading resource variable beta2_power from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/beta2_power/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
>        [[node Adam/update_dense_2/kernel/ResourceApplyAdam/ReadVariableOp_1
>
> (defined at D:/00 programs/python_ai/model/traffic_prediction_1/trainer_test_1.py:16) ]]

line 16 is :

```
apply_gradient_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, )
```

Comment: for `FailedPreconditionError ` error, I just call `tf.global_variables_initializer()` after `opitimizer` . Thus it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are calling `get_loss` and `make_train_op` within the loop, which is creating multiple loss and optimization operations. Do this instead:

```
model = Model()
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()

with tf.variable_scope('input', reuse=True):
    training_inp = InputPipe()
    validate_inp = InputPipe(is_train=False)

training_prediction, true_train_y = model(training_inp)
loss = get_loss(training_prediction, true_train_y)
train_op = make_train_op(optimizer, loss)

total_instances = data_size * n_repeats
steps_per_epoch = data_size // batch_size if data_size / batch_size == 0 else data_size // batch_size + 1

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    training_inp.init_sess(sess)
    list_grads = []
    for epoch in range(n_repeats):
        tqr = range(steps_per_epoch)
        for _ in tqr:
            sess.run(train_op)
```